# How to combine a distinct query with projection with C# MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I try to combine a projection and a distinct with the MongoDB driver but don't get anywhere...

I have:

```
var coll = db.GetCollection<Vat>(CommonConstants.VatCodeCollection);
// I like to combine in one statement:
var result = coll.Distinct<DateTime>("ValidSince", filter).ToList();    
var projection = Builders<Vat>.Projection.Expression(x => new VatPeriod { ValidSince = x.ValidSince });
```

So at the end I like to get a `List<VatPeriod>` as a result of one statement. Of course I could do something like

```
var coll = db.GetCollection<Vat>(CommonConstants.VatCodeCollection);
List<VatPeriod> vatPeriods = null;

try
{
    var result = coll.Distinct<DateTime>("ValidSince", filter).ToList();
    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        vatPeriods = new List<VatPeriod>(result.Count);
        foreach (var dateTime in result)
        {
            vatPeriods.Add(new VatPeriod() {ValidSince = dateTime});
        }
    }
    return vatPeriods;
}
catch .....
```

in my repository class, but I would prefer to do everything on the Mongo server. Any idea if and how this is possible?